# Very long running PostgreSQL function returns error

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, polling, pgadmin

I have a very long running function that took more than **30 minutes** to finish. It has a nested loop and inserts about **48 million** leads into a table in chunks of 10.000 at at time. If I pass a small dataset then it runs successfully and gives me the proper response with how many leads inserted. But if the **dataset is large** it does not give any response even if it finishes the task.

[image]

what is wrong here?

Here is my function code.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION admin.insert_data_into_table(customer_column_names text[], customer_column_ids int[] , schema_name text, dyn_table_name text, bucket_id int, partial_query text)
 RETURNS integer
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
declare
    n INTEGER := 0;
    offset_counter INTEGER := 0;
    i integer;
    chunk_size integer := 10000;
begin
    EXECUTE format('set search_path to %I', schema_name);
    EXECUTE format('SELECT count(*) FROM %I.%I', schema_name, dyn_table_name) into n;
    for i in 1..array_upper(customer_column_ids, 1)
    loop
        offset_counter = 0;
        loop
        EXIT WHEN offset_counter > n; 
            Execute Format('insert into %s.table (customer_id, customer_column_id, value, bucket_id) 
            select _customer_id, %s, %s, %s from %s.%s %s order by _customer_id offset %s limit %s', 
            schema_name, customer_column_ids[i], customer_column_names[i], bucket_id, schema_name, dyn_table_name, partial_query, offset_counter, chunk_size);
            offset_counter := offset_counter + chunk_size; 
        end loop;
    end loop;
    return n;
end;
$function$;
```

Comment: Do you commit after each chunk?

Comment: @jarlh I didn't commit implicitly. But it is inside a function, as a function is a single transaction so It should commit when the function ends successfully.

Comment: @jarlh The chunks are managed inside the function.

Comment: What's the point of chunking? Why don't you just INSERT the whole SELECT?

Comment: This will most probably be a lot faster if you just run a single `INSERT ... SELECT` statement.

Comment: This is some kind of error happening in pgAdmin itself.  Look in the PostgreSQL server log files to see if there is a corresponding report from the server's perspective.

Comment: @Dmitry Yes you have a point I was also thinking about the same before, But with different testing on different datasets, This approach seems to be most optimized, As small query runs faster then a large query.

Comment: Unfortunately, when you apply offset and limit,  you still do ordering, so essentially you reorder this dataset as many times as you have chunks. If you just insert it without any chunks, it is expected to be a lot faster. You may want to drop indexes on the destination table beforehand, and rebuild them when insert..select completes.

Comment: @Dmitry I often notice that breaking the query into smaller chunks optimize the performance. If I run the query without chunks will there be any kind of memory issue ? As there is a lot of data. regarding indexes I am not sure I could do this because many users can access the same database at a time and if there is a small file uploaded after the large one. The process of small insertion will gets completed and will enable the indexes before the large insertion gets completed.